# How can I move my aovp tests to the coin (or any other) package?

Tags: r, lm

The lmPerm package, that provided the convenient `aovp` function for a permutation-test-based ANOVA, is not supported anymore, according to CRAN. Rumor has it that the [coin](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/index.html) package might be used instead but I don't know enough stats to re-implement `aovp` with coin. Does anybody know what to do here? Is there another package for permutation tests?

Comment: Download the package source from the archive, `source` files aovp.R and summary.aovp.R and hope that the functions still work with a current R version. Or even better, try building the package from source.

Comment: Unfortunately installin aovp.R and summary.aovp.R doesn't actually work. It needs more than those files and at the end it ask for some C functions.

Comment: it does work in ubuntu though

Comment: The package is now back on CRAN. I did the adaptation to the newest CRAN regulations after the package was orphaned due to the premature death of the original author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with R version 3.0.2:

Download the tarball from CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lmPerm/
Then issue the following command at the R prompt:

```
install.packages("lmPerm_1.1-2.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source");
```

After that, the package is usable. Why it was removed from CRAN is beyond be. It weren't technical problems for sure.

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't answer the original question. In addition, it doesn't work on my current windows install.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for how to implement permutation tests in R with the `coin` package. It seems that there is no single tutorial on the Internet, but my impression is that is not as straightforward as `aovp`. The `lmperm` package is orphaned, which mean that there is nobody in charge of the package right now. For now, the options seems to install the `lmperm` from the source.

In order to do that in Windows you need `RTools`:

1. Download it from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

   ```
    https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
   ```
2. Install it making sure that you **select the option that adds it to the Windows Path** (2nd or 3rd screen of the installation). If not you will have to do add `C:\Rtools\bin` manually to the path (See Below if you forgot or didn't see it).
3. Restart R.

Then you can install the package:

1. Dowload the last version from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lmPerm/)

   ```
   https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lmPerm/
   ```
2. Install the package

   ```
   install.packages("lmPerm_1.1-2.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source");
   ```

---

**Just in case you didn't select the box to add the path in the RTools installer**

1. Go to `Control Panel >> System and Security >> System`
2. Go to `Advanced System Settings`
3. Open `Advanced` tab
4. Click `Environmental Variables...` button
5. Select `Path` variable and click `Edit` button
6. If there is nothing as a "Variable Value" you can simply write `C:\Rtools\bin`. If there is already a value, then add `;C:\Rtools\bin` to the end of it.
7. Click OK, OK...
8. Restart R, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found an alternative the `ez` package contains an `ezPerm` function. It is not as straightforward as aovp but the arguments are fairly [well documented](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ez/functions/ezPerm)